# Wordpress. Скрипты подключились, но не работают

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Скрипты, которые я подключил в файле *functions.php* подключились успешно, но отказываются работать. В чем проблема, я собственно не понимаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншот файла *functions.php*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншот консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По линкам скрипты открываются?

Comment: да, открываются

Comment: а в консоли что?

Comment: @АндрейПавлишин, какую ошибку выдает в консоли браузера?

Comment: @РашенБеар, скриншот консоли прикрепил

Comment: @GlebOstrikov, скрин прикрепил

Comment: @KAGGDesign, да, но там код 404 только у 1 css , все другое - изображения, а код выдает потому что их я еще не добавил.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Знак $ не используется в WordPress, вместо это используйте 'jQuery'.

Например:

```
var len = jQuery('.classname').length;
```

**Для того, чтобы использовать $:**

1) и скрипты загружаются в header используйте такое решение

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

// $ Works! You can test it with next line if you like
// console.log($);

});
```

2) и скрипты загружаются в footer, используйте такое решение

```
(function($) {

    // $ Works! You can test it with next line if you like
    // console.log($);

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Так замучаешься все $ на jQuery менять

Comment: Да, работает, но, да))) Есть как обойти єто?))

Comment: @KAGGDesign в Atom/Notepad в пару кликов можно.

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию, jQuery в WordPress запускается в compatibility mode.

Оборачивайте ваш код в .js файле таким образом:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
  // ваш код
}
```

и тогда внутри можете использовать $.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @АндрейПавлишин, теперь вы можете голосовать "За". https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up. Рекомендации "Когда следует голосовать" вы можете прочитать здесь https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4048/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Answer (score 0):

Вот так решаются 99% проблем

$=jQuery;

//Ваш код

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. в частности, объясните, чем он лучше и почему он не противоречит изложенному в других ответах.